# Spring Rest API Confusion

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am exploring the possibility of using a RESTful API as the backend for an Android application.

I previously have simply been using socket programming to have my clients connect to server application but since I intend to develop a web application (with the admin functionalities for the android app) I figured this may be a good option.

My backend will be required to pull data from a nosql database and run a machine learning algorithm periodically on the data. The android app will, amongst other things, query the results of the computations and provide additional information to the algorithm.

Is it possible for me to use Spring to expose some of the application functionality through a REST API while still having other functions and tasks running in the background? Basically, can I design an application that will query multiple web services and perform various scheduled computations and query and expose only some of those functions through an API ?

Am I approaching this completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach sounds fine to me. Your REST API could just call internal backend methods as needed and return their output as JSON or XML formatted data.

I recommend you, if you haven't already looked at them, to go through the Spring "Getting Started" guides for building a [RESTful web service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and [scheduling tasks](http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/).

On the Android side I'd recommend you to look into Retrofit.